# jboss cli command to get datasource connection pool details in json format

Tags: jboss, jboss-cli

using jboss cli to get connection pool details, gets output like this

```
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => {
            "ActiveCount" => 1,
            "AvailableCount" => 20L
       }
    }
```

is there a way to get the same in json format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `--output-json` argument. Something like:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --output-json "/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS/statistics=pool:read-resource(include-runtime=true)"
```

Comment: it didn't work on jboss 7.1, but some how i came to know it works on and above jboss 7.2

Comment: Ah, that `--output-json` option might only be available in JBoss EAP 7.2+